# How enable Auto Renewal to Programmatically create subscription in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, recurring-billing

I had an old v3.5 WordPress site. Where I had a user subscription system that created fully custom PHP but now I want to use WooCommerce and also want to import old subscribers as well.

So, I want to know, If I going to create subscription using my old data using `wcs_create_subscription` then is there any way I can enable auto-renewal for users? who still have tile left of their subscription. I mean when time is expired in WooCommerce can it auto-renewal without the user doing anything. because I'm going to upgrade my site but still has the same domain so I was wondering what kind of data I need to pass in order to complete this task.

And the payment method will be **opayo** (formerly sage pay)

Comment: Using WooCommerce & WooCommerce Subscription and setup will be ok. but Data migration will be super complex unless you have advanced knowledge of WordPress & WooCommerce and their DB table structure.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I know. WordPress will be ok but I don't have that much of experience of working with WooCommerce Subscription that's why I'm actually ask here for help :) if there's any example or reference I can look or follow?